# Cache existing CMake variable in Find-script?

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake macros to extract the value of certain variables that I want to export as part of my Find-script:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "([0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+" "\\1"
       MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION "${MY_PACKAGE_VERSION}"
```

How do I cache this variable after determing its value with a macro?

---

I've tried this:

```
set(MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION ${MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION}
    CACHE STRING "Major version of my package.")
```

But without `FORCE`, it detects that `MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION` is already set, and will thus not set (and thereby cache) the value output from `string`.

The only workaround I've found is to use an intermediate variable:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "([0-9]+)\\.[0-9]+" "\\1"
       _MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION "${MY_PACKAGE_VERSION}"
set(MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION ${_MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION}
    CACHE STRING "Major version of my package.")
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: AFAIK, the `string` function doesn't provide a way to set *cached* variables, so using a temporary variable, or using `FORCE`, is probably the best way.

Comment: I don't think using `FORCE` has equivalent semantics to my workaround above, as it will always overwrite the variable. `string` is just an example, this could come out of any macro, so there definitely won't be a `CACHE` option in the general case.

Comment: Yes, using `FORCE` certainly has different semantics than using the temp variable, but it's up to you to decide which is best depending on your use cases.

Comment: "But without `FORCE`, it detects that `MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION` is already set, and will thus not set (and thereby cache) the value output from string." - Strange, according to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html#set-cache-entry) the `CACHE`-ed variable should be set unless a **cached** variable with the same already exists. Since `string(REGEX REPLACE)` sets non-cached variable, this variable shouldn't affect on `set(CACHE)` command behavior. (Moreover, if `set(CACHE)` sets the **cached** variable, then the *normal* variable should be updated to the new value).

Comment: @Tsyvarev strange, I'm on CMake 3.13.3, and I just get an empty variable if I set the variable to a cached variable with the same name.

Comment: "I just get an empty variable if I set the variable to a cached variable with the same name." - What do you mean by that? Could you show the code which doing this? BTW, just checked: the cache variable is actually set (`grep MY_PACKAGE_MAJOR_VERSION CMakeCache.txt`).